# Scrap Your Boilerplate equivalent in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell

Haskell has this cool generic traversal stuff that lets you call something like `map` on every node in a collection, either bottom-up or top-down. It's called `everywhere` and you'd do something like `everywhere f tree` and `f` would be called on every node in your tree.

Writing something equivalent in Scala for `Traversable` is easy, but Haskell's also works on tuples and the equivalent of case classes or, more generically, what Scala calls `Product`s.

You can traverse over the elements in a `Product` using the `productIterator` method, but is there some easy way to put a tuple or a case class back together once you know what the arguments to the constructor (actually, I guess the `apply` method) should be?

```
def mapOnProduct[X](f: X -> X, prod: Product) {
  val newArgs = prod.productIterator.map {
    case x: X => f(x)
    case id => id
  }.toList
  [?].apply(newArgs: _*)
}
```

What can I replace `[?]` with so that this has some chance of working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Miles Sabin's Shapeless [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). There is an example of the usage of everywhere in the [sybclass test](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/sybclass.scala)

Comment: Can this take an arbitrary case class and return a new instance based on a function of its parameters, and work with all instances of Product, or is it just limited to tuples?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: this works also with case classes, at least since shapeless 2.0, thanks to macros. A nicer example is [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/e3399e35a7bb17b286141f53827619a3dc98efe8/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sybclass.scala#L65).